# How does a Bootstrap modal change the page's opacity?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When opening a Bootstrap modal (eg [the GetBootstrap modal sample](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)), the rest of the page is subtly faded out to draw attention to the modal:

[image]

How is Bootstrap accomplishing this? It seems that the class `.modal-open` is added to the body, but this only sets `overflow: hidden`. What else is Bootstrap adding/changing to cause that effect? Is the positioning of the modal within the page important?

(This is a roundabout way of asking why my modal *isn't* fading out the background when it's open. The code is too complicated to post, and presumably there's a flaw in my markup or CSS. If I knew how Bootstrap was accomplishing the opaque background I may be able to debug why it's not working for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap add a div and adds some classes to it. Which has black background with .5 opacity set. And add style to set height as viewport / browser screen.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 984px;"></div>
```

If your modal is not fading out, check if you are using :

```
display:block!important /* notice !important */
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For some reason the height on the modal-backdrop div wasn't set, but top, left and right were all 0. I added `bottom: 0` to that class and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the modal appears, it adds a div container with the class `modal-backdrop fade in` before the `modal-dialog` container.